# File upload to ftp and sftp

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

I am stuck in a problem. According to my latest requirement, I have to upload a file to ftp or sftp server. Problem is that I don't know that the server is ftp or sftp. On runtime client will provide the ip and other details of the server where I have to upload a file. So, in runtime I have to understand that the server is ftp or sftp and then need to act accordingly. So, is there any way out on this?

Comment: get ftp and sftp clients, try connecting either way, and see what goes through? it's not rocket science... if the front door (ftp) is locked, go around back and try sftp.

Comment: When researching this problem, be sure to find out if it really is `sftp` and not `ftps` or `ftp over ssh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) uses port 22 by default.

Some people use "SFTP" to denote the FTPS (FTP-over-TLS). In this case you have two options: explicit TLS and implicit TLS. Implicit TLS uses port 990 by default. In explicit mode the client connects to port 21 by default and then tells the server to start TLS handshake over existing connection.

Plain FTP uses port 21.

Now, the user can be able to specify explicitly what protocol to use.

Finally you can try to connect, grab the first line of data from the socket and analyze it. In FTP/FTPS first line should start with 220SP (SP stands for space, character with the code of 0x20). Other response code can be given as well. In SSH/SFTP the line starts with "SSH-2.0-" .

Comment: ftp and sftp will use different ports (21 and 22 respectively). This should be part of the "ip and other details of the server". So, how to get the code from there? Could you give me a example?

Comment: @Souvik I am not sure that I understand your question. Which code do you want to get from where?

Comment: My client will only provide me the IP(Not the port, if FTP i have to make it 21 else 22) user name and password at runtime but no information about the server is ftp or sftp. I have to connect to the server and need to identify that the server is a FTP server or SFT one.So, is there any programm can be written with java to identify that.

Comment: @Souvik you must have a (port OR protocol) specified by the user. Without any of them there's no way for you to know where to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

ftp and sftp will use different ports (21 and 22 respectively). This should be part of the "ip and other details of the server".

Comment: My programm will determine the port according to the server.So is there any way to identify the FTP or SFTP in server